# Magento - No products are showing at front end nor admin panel , though csv file imported successfully

Tags: csv, magento, import, product

I have referred related questions, but the solutions didn't work at my case. Hence, raising a question.

I have imported csv file to import products in our magento store.

Products are imported successfully from admin panel import functionality and also from Data flow - Profile functionality

But, There are no products getting displayed at front end nor at admin panel.

If anyone has faced such issue, please help to solve the issue.

Please note : All products are simple new products.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case,

I have created one new spreadsheet in open office and have copied all the data of import file.

I saved it again with UTF-8 encoding and .csv format.

And then, i have tried to import it again.

With this process, i was able to import all the products successfully as magento admin panel has considered it as completely new file for import.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I've also faced such issue. So you need to flush all Magento cache and reindex data. It can solve your problem. But first of all, you need to check in the database that products are stored or not by given below query. 
select count(*) from 'catalog_product_entity';

Or you can check given below URL for more detail:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53157/products-exist-in-the-database-but-are-not-showing-in-backend-or-frontend

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In some cases, your answer will work. One Up-vote for you. :)